# How to create a directory with PHP?

Tags: php

In my php web page I want to create a directory under the current directory ( `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` ). How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's [`mkdir()`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function. Make sure to test for errors too:

```
if (!mkdir('directory')) { //ERROR! Directory not created! }
```

Comment: This isn't going to work all the times for a current file directory.

Comment: Create a file in subdirectory, add your code there and call it by including in a file in current directory. You'll see that new directory will be at the current directory, not where that file is.

Answer (score 3):

With the [`mkdir`](http://php.net/mkdir) function.,

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

```
mkdir("/path/to/dir", 0700);  // Linux

mkdir("c:/path/to/dir"); // Windows - windoes ignore modes
```

Also on windows note the slash direction is not as you'd expect :)

**EDIT**

To detect if Windows/Linux:

```
$os_string = php_uname('s');
if (strpos(strtoupper($os_string), 'WIN')!==false) {
    echo 'Windows';
} else {
    echo 'Linux';
}
```

You may also need to play with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to determine the paths.

Comment: If the operating system is not known because the project will be sold to any clients , so the clients may use different operating systems. So how to write a generic function for creating the directory ?

Comment: See Edit for simple OS detection... you can use this to DEFINE to create some root paths to prepend onto what you want to create.

Answer (score 1):

Use the build-in php function [mkdir](http://php.net/mkdir).

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir(__DIR__.'/'.$dir_name);
```

See also: http://php.net/mkdir